# intellij idea complains about "bad return type in lambda expression" but code compile fine

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, lambda, java-8

I write these code for Spark, it compiles and runs fine but intellij-idea complains "bad return type in lambda expression" on it.
code:

```
Map<String, List<Batch>> hubCode2BatchMap = wdBatchRdd.map(Batch::new)
            .mapToPair(batch -> new Tuple2<>(batch.getHubCode(), batch))
            .combineByKey(this::createCombiner, (list1, batch) -> {
                list1.add(batch);
                return list1;
            }, (list1, list2) -> {
                list1.addAll(list2);
                return list1;
            })
            .collectAsMap();
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PzpC.png)

my project Language level setting is "8 - Lambdas,type annotations etc."
And I'm using intellij 2016.2.2.

Comment: what's your intellij version??

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2
Build #IU-162.1628.40, built on August 16, 2016
Subscription is active until February 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_65-b17 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Comment: what is the line?? For me updating to 2016 from 2014 fixed all those problems.

Comment: It can see in the picture

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7PzpC.png

Comment: You should report it as a bug on their bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: it really is a bug,i reproduce the bug at this idea version by another code. but idea version 2016.1.2 no this problem with same code.  I open your link but i have no permission to create a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an idea bug. these code can trigger this bug:

```
package com.oasis.wyvern.spark.common.util;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.Map;

public class BugTest {
    private static void test1(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
        // this line will be report error
        rdd.mapToPair(xx -> new Tuple2<>(xx.length(), xx));
    }
    private static void test() {
        // this line will be report error
        new BugClass<String>().testBug(xx -> new Tuple2<>(xx.length(), xx));
    }
    private static class BugClass<E> {
        <T1, T2> Map<T1, T2> testBug(PairFunction<E, T1, T2> func) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```